# civicrm "relationships" not visible after migrating wordpress test site to live site

Tags: wordpress, relationships

Moved my test wordpress site from my laptop to live, database works i can see all the names but i cannot see the relationships, even if i assign a new relationship the number goes up but the relation does not show.

Comment: Did you include the `civicrm_relationship_cache` table in the migration?